# C# attribute to pass in name of the property a computed value will be assigned to

Tags: c#

I have created a helper method that parses values from an XML node, but at this moment I have to pass in the name of the property to value has to be assigned to.

I know of the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, but I wonder whether there is an attribute that can be used to automatically get the Property name the value will be assigned to.

For example:

## Current situation

I have this extension method:

```
public static string GetStringValueOrDefault(this XmlNode node, string elementName) =>
    node[elementName]?.InnerText ?? default;
```

Which is called like this:

```
PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerSettingsElement.GetStringValueOrDefault(nameof(PrinterSettings.PrinterName))
```

## Desired situation

The same extension method, with an attribute:

```
public static string GetStringValueOrDefault(this XmlNode node, [AssigneeName] string elementName) =>
    node[elementName]?.InnerText ?? default;
```

I made up the `[AssigneeName]` attribute, but I guess you get the idea.

Which should be called like this, which is much cleaner:

```
PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerSettingsElement.GetStringValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: sounds like some secret extension method created for the `PropertyName` attribute (which will need to be made a custom type maybe) might be worth giving it a try...but it might turn out to be an overkill too in case you are able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: there isn't.

And there cannot be in general. And if it only works in some cases then what would the hypothetical `AssigneeNameAtttribute` do when there is no property being assigned to?

Consider:

```
var temp = doc.GetStringValueOrDefault();
outputDoc.Prop = temp;
```

Not only is `temp` not helpful for the `elementName` parameter value of `GetStringValueOrDefault` it is likely to be removed by the optimiser leading to different behaviour depending on compilation settings.

Unlike `CallerMemberNameAttribute` – there is always a caller – the assignee may not exist is any useful format. Consider another case:

```
var results = doc.Elements()
                  .Select(e => new { e.Name, Value = e.GetStringValueOrDefault())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Very good points.
In your first example, `elementName` will be `temp`, while it should be `Prop`. I don't see an inssue with the second example, since it will be `Value`.

Comment: @JohanVergeer in the second example for every element, get the string for `Value`... doesn't seem useful. Surely you would want the value for `e.Name`?